# automatically comparing the server's date from a specific range of dates from SQL table itself

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq, datetime

This is my table:

[image]

I have a table named `term calendar` that has the following columns

```
id         = record number
schoolyear = year specificed
tstart     = term start
tend       = term end
regenroll  = advance enrollment
regend     = end of advance enrollment
nenroll    = normal enrollment
nend       = end of normal enrollment
ienroll    = late enrollment
iend       = end of late enrollment
```

the dates are in format of `DateTime` on my SQL table.

What i want to happen is that, when the action is first called aka when the user logged in. The server's current `DateTime` will be used to compare if they are within the range of `tstart` and `tend` and i will get the `schoolyear` and `term` from that.

Now my question is, what should my sql/linq query be?

I researched about `DateTime` earlier and the examples that i found relies on the `where` clause with a pre-specified set of range but my range is from the database itself. Do i need to redesign my table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should meet your request:

```
DECLARE @checkDate DATETIME

SET @checkDate = GETDATE();

SELECT tc.schoolyear ,
       tc.term
FROM termcalendar tc
WHERE
       tc.start <= @checkDate
       AND tc.tend >= @checkDate
```

You should take care of periods that isn't return any records like `2015-04-02`.

Comment: I copy pasted your code and tried running it, here is what i get `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'end'.`

Comment: I was a mistake with name of field. It should be `tend` enstead of `end`. I corrected query,

Comment: ohhhh i see, alright.if i decided to set the time is it still the same?

Comment: Yes. I set time to variable to make sure that will be the same.

Comment: I plan on putting the time sooner or later so it will be something like `2015-08-07 12:00:00..`. do i need to  change anything from your query?